# UILongPressGesture to Touches Moved in subview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved, long-press

I have a `UIViewController` and have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` which when is recognised adds a subview on top which covers the `UIViewController` and pass the coordinates of the press to the subview and adds an image where the press was.

What I now need to do is move the subview where the users thumb goes. I have implemented `touchesMoved` in the `UIView` but this does not register until you remove the gesture and press and start again?

How can I get the touchesBegan to start as soon as the `UIView` is added without having to remove and start again?

Thanks
-JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just continue using UILongPressGesture?

```
    - (IBAction)longPressGestureStateChanged:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        switch (sender.state) {
            case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            /* PUT YOUR IMAGE HERE */
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            /* MOVE YOUR IMAGE HERE */
            self.myImageView.center = [sender locationInView:self.view /* or any of your subviews */];
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            /* REMOVE OR PROCESS END OF THIS TOUCH GESTURE */
            break;
    }
}
```